# Assign roles to users in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I am trying to update a users role using mongoose . I have been using mongoose findOneAndUpdate but have not been able to update the role. I dont get any error messages but i get the doc before the update. So i did some research and tried to add `{new:true}` but it did not change anything. Then I saw someone use the aggregate query `$push` but that did not either work.

I have rewritten this query many times without giving me the expected results

```
 exports.changeRole = async (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: req.param.userId },
    {
      $push: {
        $set: { "roles[0].name": req.body.name },
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .populate("roles", "-__v")
    .exec((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
};
```

How I send in postman

```
{
"roles": ["Admin"]
}
```

This is what i get in my console:

```
{
  roles: [ { _id: 606242fa3bcbc13305bee567, name: 'user' } ],
  _id: 606307a839a54f7982f8ff84,
  username: 'before',
  email: 'before@gmail.com',
  password: '$2a$/lvMv80IPZe9FSm',
  __v: 1
}
```

I have one model that is called User

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
      max: 255,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
      max: 255,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
      max: 15,
    },
    roles: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Role",
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamp: true }
);
```

This User model is referencing to Role.js. An array of objectId:s. So automatically I have four role documents created if they dont exist. Every user is referencing to one of those documents(roles)

```
const Role = mongoose.model(
  "Role",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
  })
);
```

Comment: `req.body.name` i think should be `req.body.roles` as per what you're sending from postman.

Comment: Okay, I changed but I still get the the same output in console. It finds and populates but it does not update anything. It makes me wonder if need to use several querys to update? @TusharGupta-curioustushar

Comment: Try `$set: { "roles.0.name": req.body.roles }`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Nothing. It still console.logs the before it gets updated

Comment: Use `await` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: `code
exports.changeRole = async (req, res) => {
  await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: req.param.userId },
    {
      $push: {
        $set: { "roles[0].name": req.body.roles },
      },
    },
    { new: true }
  )
    .populate("roles")
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) return res.status(404).send("Not found");
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
`         @TusharGupta-curioustushar Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I was not thinking it right. I did not need to change my populated documents only needed to change the objectId it was referencing to in my `roles:[]` in User.js. Use $set to change a field and $push to to add new value.

```
exports.changeRole = async (req, res) => {
  await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { id: req.params.userId },
    {
      $set: { roles: req.body.roles },
    },

    { new: true }
  )
    .populate("roles")
    .then((data) => {
      if (!data) return res.status(404).send("Not found");
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```